# How to add scope in all urls paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

Using scopes in rails

```
scope '(:client)', :constraints => {:locale => /client1|client2/} do
resources :categories

resources :order_steps do
  member do
    get :no_of_tickets
    get :order_succesfully
  end
end 

resources :orders do 
  member do
    post :mark_order_success
  end
end

resources :users do
  resources :products
  resources :subscriptions
end

resources :events do
  collection do
    get :check_subdomain
    post :repeat_form
    post :search
    get :search
  end
end

root to: "home#index"
end
```

So when I access `localhost:3000/client1` or `localhost:3000/client2` it works fine but issue is that when I click on any link on pages it's not keeping the same client scope.

How can I make sure that scope is part of all urls.

Comment: Can you share you routes file?

Comment: @MoizMansur yes question updated :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for namespace and not scope.

Check [rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) for more details.

Comment: yes but don't wanna change Controller#Action

Comment: Can you share the results for rake routes